# How to save a user to a post when it is created

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am trying to display the name of the user that made a post in octobercms but haven't gotten it to work yet. This is what I have already done. I have extended the userModel in the boot method of my plugin.

```
  public function boot()
{ 
         User::extend(function($model){
        $model->hasMany['adverts'] = ['Corymillz\Adverts\Models\Advert'];
    }); 
}
```

and in my main plugin I have

```
public $belongsTo = [ 
'user' => [
'RainLab\User\Models\User', 'key' => 'user_id']
];
```

In my twig template i am trying something  like `{{ ads.user.name }}` for the specific user. This works correctly but how to i attach a post to a logged in user. Don't know if i am asking the question right. When a logged in user makes a post. His name should appear with it using `{{ ads.user.name}}`  instead of me manually adding a user to a post in the backend

With user_id in my advert table
I have tried adding this to my form .php file but returns an error

$advert->user_id = Auth ::user()->id;
$advert->save();

Comment: I think that in your create method you are not assigned any specific user. Do you want to add that piece of code?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. But the general idea of what i want to do is after setting up the relationship up there, if Mr.A is logged in and he makes a post Mr. A should appear with the post using ```{{ads.user.name}}```. Don't know how to save the user to the post when it's made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding
`use Auth;`

at the top of the file and

`$advert->user_id = Auth ::user()->id; $advert->save();`